# How do i add 1 month to a date that already has been created on VB?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Hi I'm new to coding and am looking for some help! I've been trying to add 1 month to a date that I've already stored in my database and displayed on a gridview.

```
Dim dueDate As DateTime = lblDateA.Text.AddMonth(1)
```

I know the way that I've done it is wrong but i hope you get the idea i'm going for! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the date to a DateTime and add Month to it.

```
Dim dueDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(lblDateA.Text).AddMonths(1)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! i would up vote but my rep is too low sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `Text` of a `Label` is a `String`, so you can't add a month to it.  Whatever you're displaying in that Label should already be being stored in a `DateTime` variable somewhere.  You would then add one month to that and then display the new value, e.g.

```
Me.dateA = Me.dateA.AddMonths(1)
lblDateA.Text = Me.dateA.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got a question tho, what exactly is Me? is it like This.DateA but for VB?

Comment: `Me` in VB is a reference to the current instance, equivalent to `this` in C# and other C-based languages.  I used it here specifically to indicate that that variable would be a member and not local.  I'm not sure why you had to ask that here though, given that you have a "Help" menu on your IDE and access to an internet search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You convert the text to a `Date` and then add the month.

```
Private Function ConvertDGVDateAndAddMonth(dateAsString As String) As Date
 Dim dt As Date
 If Date.TryParse(dateAsString, dt) Then
   'parsed correctly so we can use the dt variable as a date
   Return dt.AddMonth(1)
 End If
 'if it does not convert return Nothing
 Return Nothing
End Function
```

USage:

```
Dim dt As Date = ConvertDGVDate(dgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString)
'if this does not convert dt = Nothing
'be sure to check
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appreciate it!